# How to override an interface fault tolerance annotation in application.properties

Tags: quarkus, application.properties, fault-tolerance, microprofile

I am trying to override an interface Timeout Fault tolerance annotation in application.properties. However I am not sure if it is possible to override annotation parameters via configuration file using property [classname/methodname/]annotation/parameter for an interface?
Any idea what would be the syntax for interface?

Here is my ReST client Interface:

```
package com.myProject;

@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "test")
@Timeout
public interface MyInterface{
    @POST
    @Path("/my-endpoint")
    Uni<AResponse> create(ARequest request);
}
```

And here is my application.properties:

```
com.myProject.MyInterface/Timeout/value=2000
```

looking into the Quarkus dev UI dashboard, Timeout value is still 1000 which is the default value.

Comment: Are you using RestClient Reactive? If so, you will see in the dashboard that the bean class isn't `MyInterface`, it's `MyInterface$$CDIWrapper`. So that is what you need to configure.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer to my question:

com.myProject.MyInterface$$CDIWrapper/Timeout/value=2000

This is exactly what can be seen in dev UI MyInterface$$CDIWrapper and I needed to use the same in the application.properties.

Answer (score -1):

### Just set it in annotation

You could try setting it directly in the annotation value like this :

```java
@Timeout(2000)
```

### And override in `application.properties` if needed

According to [SmallRye Fault Tolerance Documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-fault-tolerance), you should be able to override value using one of these :

- `annotation-name/property-name=value`
- `fully-qualified-class-name/method-name/annotation-name/property-name=value`

Which in your case should be :

```
Timeout/value=2000
```

Or

```
com.myProject.MyInterface/create/Timeout/value=2000
```

Notice I only added method name `create` to the latest one

### Edit

I believe you have to set your annotation `@Timeout` at the method level and add value like example above

```java
package com.myProject;

@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "test")
public interface MyInterface{
    @POST
    @Timeout(2000)
    @Path("/my-endpoint")
    Uni<AResponse> create(ARequest request);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jacouille,
I need it in `application.properties` and I tried with and without the method name, and neither worked.

Comment: I edited my answer, I believe you have to defined timeout at method level

Comment: Problem solved.
I needed to configure it this way `MyInterface$$CDIWrapper` as can be seen in the dev UI.
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/32774#issuecomment-1515872372

Comment: You should write an answer with your solution, it may be useful to someone

Comment: You should post it as an answer (not a comment), and then you can accept your answer. It'll provide more visibility to solution for future user seeking solution.